# Grid row not expanding as expected with fr unit

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

In the example below, `.grid-container` has `grid-template-rows: 1fr` set, but the row does not grow, even though there is plenty of extra room. It seems to behave like `grid-template-rows: auto`. Any ideas as to what's going on here? As a sidenote, this is a contrived demo for practice, there are better ways to lay this out, but I'm curious about why it doesn't work like I expect. Thanks for any help!

**Update** - Appears to work as expected in Firefox and Safari, but not Chrome.

```css
.flex-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Grid Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems you discovered a bug

Comment: seems like flex-grow has an effect on it..try removing it

Comment: it's related to the min-height, using height will work fine